# Text Field и переход по URL

Tags: xcode, ios

Добрый день, я уже задавал этот вопрос, но некорректно выразился, за что меня обругали, так что попытаюсь реабилитироваться. В моем проекте Xcode есть View Controller, на котором расположен Text Field. Задача такая: при вводе слова "calendar" должен выполнятся переход по url-ссылке "calshow://", которая откроет iOS- приложение Календарь. В файле ViewController.m я написал такой код:

```
- (IBAction)textField:(id)sender
{
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]);
int x, calendar;
scanf("%d", &x);
if(x==calendar)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"calshow://"]];
}
}
```

Но при запуске программы после ввода слова calendar кнопка enter не работает и ничего не происходит.
Надеюсь на вашу помощь.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализуйте ваш метод таким образом, предварительно присоедините IBAction в storyboard/XIB на событие текстфилда Did End On Exit

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDidEndOnExit:(UITextField *)sender 
    {
         [sender resignFirstResponder];
         if ([sender.text isEqualToString:@"calendar"]) {
               NSURL *calURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"calshow://"];
               if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:calURL]) {
                   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:calURL];
               }
         }
    }
```

Не могли бы вы объяснить, где в принципе вы могли взять это:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]);
int x, calendar;
scanf("%d", &x);
if(x==calendar)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А "это" я взял из учебника по obj-c, там этот код использовался для ввода пользователем данных в приложениях без UI.